# SQL - Specified field could relate to more than one table

Tags: sql

I am a beginner to SQL and have been playing around with it. There are two tables. One called `Customers` and one called `Orders`. I am doing a count on how many orders are related to the customer ID but it keeps throwing up an error. I have the following code:

```
SELECT CustomerID, COUNT (orders.OrderID) AS TotalOrders
FROM Customers AS cust, Orders AS orders
WHERE cust.CustomerID = orders.CustomerID
```

It throws up an error that the `CustomerID` field could appear in more than one table.

If I change the `SELECT CustomerID` to `ContactName` for example, the query will work fine. However, I know the problem is that the `CustomerID` field is in both the `Customers` and `Orders` table. Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT cust.CustomerID, COUNT (orders.OrderID) AS TotalOrders
FROM Customers AS cust
JOIN Orders AS orders ON cust.CustomerID = orders.CustomerID
GROUP BY cust.CustomerID
```

This query uses *explicit* `JOIN` syntax that is ANSI standard. This is best practice. The only thing you were missing was the `GROUP BY` to group the aggregate. You also want to make sure that prefix the table name to the column to prevent ambiguity.

Comment: Orders AS orders - legit syntax, but... OP had it - I'd still remove the pointless alias.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. When I execute your query I get the error 'syntax error in FROM clause'. If its any help this is the query that works perfect: SELECT ContactName, COUNT (orders.OrderID) AS TotalOrders
FROM Customers AS cust, Orders AS orders
WHERE cust.CustomerID = orders.CustomerID
GROUP BY ContactName

Comment: @DavidMann What DBMS are you using?

Comment: Sorry for the double post but I fixed it by changing JOIN to INNER JOIN. I know it sounds stupid but why did that work and not just JOIN? Also working code here: SELECT cust.CustomerID, COUNT (orders.OrderID) AS TotalOrders
FROM Customers AS cust

INNER JOIN Orders AS orders ON cust.CustomerID = orders.CustomerID
GROUP BY cust.CustomerID

Comment: And I'm using Microsoft Access. As I am a total beginner. But thanks to you I got it working FINALLY! Absolute legend man :)

Comment: @DavidMann Glad to hear it works. Next time you create a question it will be helpful to `tag` it with the appropriate DBMS.

Answer (score 1):

You have to qualify the field name with the tablename, or an alias... Using Aliases is recommended.
Also, recommend you switch to ANSI-92 Join syntax.

```
  SELECT c.CustomerID, COUNT (o.OrderID) AS TotalOrders
  FROM Customers c Join Orders o 
     On c.CustomerID = o.CustomerID
  GROUP BY c.CustomerID
```

Answer (score -1):

Should be:

```
SELECT cust.CustomerID, COUNT (orders.OrderID) AS TotalOrders
FROM Customers AS cust, Orders AS orders
WHERE cust.CustomerID = orders.CustomerID
```

Comment: Missing `GROUP BY`; looks like the original.